# $x^3-9x-5=0$, then what is $x^4-18x^3-81x^2-12$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

If we have $x^3-9x-5=0$, then what $x^4-18x^3-81x^2-12$ equals to?

This is a multiple choices question. 
A)$5$ B)$25$ C)$42$ D)$67$ E)$81$.

My attempt,

By long division of polynomials, we have $x^4-18x^3-81x^2-12=(x-18)(x^3-9x-5)+(-72x^2-157x-102)$

Since $x^3-9x-5=0$, whatever $x$ could be, $x^4-18x^3-81x^2-12=-72x^2-157x-102$

How to proceed?

P/S. Conclusion, NONE of the options can be right.

Comment: None of the options can be right. Asking Wolfram Alpha to compute the polynomial GCD of $x^3-9x-5$ and $x^2-18x^2-81x^2-12-N$ gives $1$ for $N\in\{5,24,42,67,81\}$ i.e. the two polynomials don't have any factor (and therefore also no root) in common.

Comment: Alternatively, the three numerical zeros of the polynomial $x^3-9x-5$ may be substituted into $x^4-18x^3-81x^2-12$. All three results are negative, so none of the answers is correct.

Comment: Another reason none of the answers are correct: $x^4−18x^3−81x^2−12$ is negative on $[-3,21]$ (via Wolfram alpha), and all of the roots of $x^3-9x-5$ lie within that interval.

Comment: Solve this equation for x, and then substitute.

Comment: Recheck the question. You have probably transcribed it incorrectly.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the decomposition
$$x^4-18x^3-81x^2-12=x^2(x^2-18x-81)-12$$

Observe the roots of the equation  $x^3-9x-5=0$ must belong to the following two intervals: $(-3,-2)$ and $(3,4)$.

The axis of symmetry of this function $f=x^2-18x-81$ is $x=9$, so the trend of the function is decreasing for $x < 9$, so observe:

$$\begin{array} {cccc} f(-3)<0&f(-2)<0&f(3)<0&f(4)<0\end{array}$$

So the function $f=x^2-18x-81<0$ in the interval of $(-3,-2)$ to $(3,4)$.

Since $x^2>0$ and $-12<0$, then $x^2(x^2-18x-81)-12$ must be less than zero. Since all the given options are positive, none of them can be right.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use synthetic substitution to solve for $x$ in the first equation, then plug that value into the second.

Comment: Huh? It looks like "synthetic substitution" is a particular way to _evaluate_ a polynomial, not to find its roots. One can solve that polynomial with Cardano's formula, but the expressions for the roots are pretty horrible.

Comment: None of the options can be right. 

The values of the first equations are $-2.6697$, $-0.57689$ and $3.2466$